# Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"

Tags: docker

I use Docker on Windows, and when I tried to pull a PHP image with this command

```
$ docker pull php
```

I got this message:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/php no matching manifest for windows/amd64 
        in the manifest list entries
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: To help others, I got into this error while creating image for linux as base OS.... Reason for this error was it was set for windows containers so then I switched to Linux containers then it started working...

Comment: Also, for posterity: I got this building a Windows container. Even though I switched to Windows, it appears to have switched back to Linux.  Changing it back to Windows fixed the problem.

Answer (score 385, accepted):

I had this same issue on Windows 10 (2020) and Windows 11 (2023).
I bypassed it by running the Docker daemon in experimental mode:

1. Right click Docker icon in the Windows System Tray
2. Go to *Settings*
3. Select Docker Engine
4. Edit the Docker daemon file
5. Set the `"experimental": true`
6. Click Apply & Restart Docker

Comment: Besides the previous answers, I also had to remove "read only" attribute of my C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.etc

Comment: On Windows, you can locate the config file directly at '%programdata%\docker\config\daemon.json' and set the attributes there.

Comment: This worked for me and I was just wondering why does this work? What is experimental for?

Comment: If you're running docked (daemon) from standalone binary use `--experimental` feature

Comment: Couldn't edit via graphic interface. Had to use **Cmder as administrator** and run commands `cd C:\ProgramData\Docker\config` and `nano daemon.json` to set **experimental** value to **true**, and then restart Docker (right click on the icon near the clock at right bottom - click on the arrow to show hidden icons)

Comment: setting  "experimental": true has any security issues? do I need to revert back once operation completed?

Comment: so what is being *experimented*?

Comment: thanks this worked for me, nothing else on the net was working, come on docker.

Comment: switch to linux is working

Answer (score 356):

There could be many reasons for this error. But most obvious reason for this error is using Windows Container in Linux Container Mode or vice versa.

1. Right-click Docker icon in the System Tray to open its context menu
2. Click "Switch to Windows/Linux Containers..."
3. Click the Switch button in the dialog (it may take little time)
4. Make sure Docker is in Running state now

[image: Switch Container Mode Dialog]

Comment: It solved my problem about "no matching manifest for windows/amd64"

Comment: It worked for me with the issue 'no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries'

Comment: This answer is irrelevant for Windows Container. It only works if your container requirement is Linux Container. 

Please refer to @benscabbia's answer.

Comment: Hi @junnyea, I tried to explain for both cases, so if you are on Windows Container in user, then Linux Containers Settings will not work and you may have to move to Windows Containers Settings, and vise versa.

Comment: For my case, I need to run it in a Windows architecture. There is no point to switch to a Linux container. It will be more relevant if the solution given was not switching between container.

Comment: If you can't find the system tray icon, this command will do it, on PowerShell

`& $Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon .`

See here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to run a Windows container off of the `node` image, and there isn't a Windows version of the `node` image, apparently. This answer helped me further: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72583505/2552903

Answer (score 111):

You are in Windows container mode. So if you're not sure that the image you want to pull **is built for the Windows architecture**, you need to switch to Linux containers.

Comment: The alternative (that I also found to be working) is in [chuck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries/49785458#49785458)

Comment: once it failures to switch ? it's a work around way

Comment: If you switch to Linux Containers will you then be able to host Windows applications within Docker? For example using IIS and MySQL on the same Docker instance.

Comment: @webworm since there's also MySQL for Windows, why use a Linux version when you want to mix it with IIS and not just use its Windows version?

Answer (score 76):

In my case it was that the Windows OS version I was on did not support the tag I was trying to pull.  Utilizing an older tag allowed me to get this to work.

Specifically:

`docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1903` errored

`docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1803-amd64` worked

Comment: This! Microsoft changed there something compared to the old images (servercore/nanoserver). Now, you need to lookup the windows version of the system for which you're deploying to and choose the base image accordingly.

Comment: Nice answer! This worked for me on Windows 10 following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/run-your-first-container

Comment: It also worked for me. But does it mean that I need to have this approach when I pull every image, for eg hello-world?

Comment: @Mandroid I would be interested in your findings but some images seemed to work and some didn't in my case, so I'd guess it's very setup specific.  e.g. if you have one Windows patch may vary from another.

Comment: Use `winver` to make sure that the windows version of your host machine is newer or equal to the version in the image.

Comment: In order to pull windows server on windows 10, I had to go back to the earliest tag: win10-21h1-preview

Answer (score 64):

Version: Windows 10

Step 1: Right click Docker instance and Go to Settings
[image]

Step 2: Basic to Advanced and setting the "experimental": true
[image]

Step 3: Restart Docker
[image]

Step 4: To install dockerfile is successful( ex: docker build -t williehao/cheers2019 . )
[image]

Answer (score 39):

Another possible way to do this:

In system tray, right click on docker icon, then click on `Switch to Linux containers`.

(Docker for Windows, Community Edition, version 18.03.1)

Answer (score 23):

I solved this in Windows 10 by running in admin Powershell:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
```

And then:

```
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

Comment: This can also be done by right clicking the Docker Desktop icon and selecting `Switch to Windows Containers` / `Switch to Linux Containers` as required.  NB: You'll still get issues if the Windows image you're installing is ahead of your host version of windows (e.g. see OS Version column: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows)

Answer (score 17):

## Update for Windows 10 20H2

1. Go to Docker configurations
2. Go to the Docker Engine tab
3. Change the line `"experimental": false` to `"experimental": true`
4. Restart Docker using the `Apply & Restart` button

[image]

---

**You can also modify the configuration file manually by opening it with your favorite code editor *(Visual code, Notepad++...)*, like this for example:**

```
# BACKUP Your file with PowerShell
Copy-Item -Path C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json -Destination C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json.backup

# Open the file with Visual Code
code C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json
```

Or change the string directly with Powershell

```
# Set Path in variable
$FILE = "C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json"

# Replace '"experimental": false' to '"experimental": true'
(Get-Content -Path $FILE) -replace '"experimental": false','"experimental": true' | Set-Content -Path $FILE

# Check the file content
type $FILE
```

Output example

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> type $FILE
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": false,
  "experimental": true
}
```

After your need restart the Docker daemon

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Restart-Service docker
```

Check the status of the service

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Service docker
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  docker             Docker Engine
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to pull with the Linux platform first, then you can run on Windows:

```
docker pull --platform linux php
docker run -it php
```

See blog post *[Docker for Windows Desktop 18.02 with Windows 10 Fall Creators Update](https://blog.docker.com/2018/02/docker-for-windows-18-02-with-windows-10-fall-creators-update/)*.

Comment: Yes, the `--platform` flag works too. Though it may redownload stuff.

Comment: "--platform" is only supported on a Docker daemon with experimental features enabled

Answer (score 9):

In Docker:

1. go to **Settings**
2. go to **Docker Engine**
3. change **experimental** to **true**
4. press **Apply and Restart**

.

Answer (score 8):

This looks like ["docker pull" fails in windows 10 #1100](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1100#issuecomment-350545769)

If adding `--experimental` does not work, consider [re-installing docker for windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/).

Comment: Adding "experimental: true" didn't work for me, so I thought I'd try switching to the Linux container before re-installing docker and it worked.

Comment: On Windows enviroment, also check if Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service is running, then after installing docker, switch it to Linux containers mode.

Comment: Adding `experimental` works , thanks... Why is that so ?

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal Using experimental features (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#command-line) adds drivers (https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/experimental/README.md#current-experimental-features) which might be needed for using Docker for Windows.

Answer (score 6):

This just happened to me after I upgraded Docker Desktop (previously configured with WSL2 integration.)

In case you ran into this after an upgrade, just FYI that I had to do the following:

Run PowerShell in Administrator (elevated) mode and execute the following commands:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

If you don't do this, you might not be able to open up the Settings tab on Docker Desktop.

Then, you need to switch to Linux Containers in Settings (by ***unchecking*** "Use the WSL2 based engine"), then restart.

[image]

At this point, just run a quick test that downloads an image and runs a container off it, to see if that solves the issue:

```
docker run --rm -ti alpine:latest uname -a
Linux 2b08b155a042 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Oct 28 23:40:43 UTC 2020 x86_64 Linux
```

From there, if you were running with WSL2 integration, simply go back to the Settings screen and undo the selection we did in step number two (which will restart docker.)

At that point, you will see all images and stopped containers you had prior to the upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

```
docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016
```

try the above command.
what you are pulling should be compatible with the underlying windows version you are in. above will work if you are in windows server 2016.

follow this thread for more info

- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3761

Comment: This is true for `ltsc2019` vs `ltsc2022` as well. One of my computers (newer) could run 22, but my other computer couldn't.

Answer (score 5):

Right click Docker instance
Go to Settings
Daemon
Advanced
Set the "experimental": true
Restart Docker

```
 {
      "registry-mirrors": [],
      "insecure-registries": [],
      "debug": true,
      "experimental": true
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered this error when I started learning docker and my understanding of this scenario is below:

**why you hit this issue:**
Because you're referring the image of Linux based and you're currently using windows base platform to run/ build docker image.

Resolution:
Short answer: Either switch your current platform to Linux mode or pull the windows based image.
Here is the list of possible options:

1. Switch to Linux Containers as the error is "***no matching manifest for windows/amd64***"
2. Set the docker environment "experimental": true.
3. Pull the image specific to a platform
   e.g. docker pull --platform {linux/Windows} {image-name}

Answer (score 4):

**Deprecating the ‘latest’ tag**

We are deprecating the ‘latest’ tag across all our Windows base images to encourage better container practices. **At the beginning of the 2019 calendar year, we will no longer publish the tag** ; We’ll yank it from the available tags list.

We strongly **encourage** you to instead declare the specific container tag you’d like to run in production. The ‘latest’ tag is the opposite of specific; it doesn’t tell the user anything about what version the container actually is apart from the image name. You can read more about version compatibility and selecting the appropriate tag on our [container docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-1909%2Cwindows-10-1909#matching-container-host-version-with-container-image-versions) .

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/windows-server-2019-now-available/ba-p/382430#

Answer (score 3):

Consider the applications that you are pulling - are they Windows based?
If not, you need to run a Linux container.

Without using the experimental mode, you can only use Docker in one style of container vs the other.
If you activate the experimental mode as mentioned above, you can use Windows and Linux containers as required by the applications you are pulling in the compose file.

Key note: Experimental - still in development by Docker.

Answer (score 3):

This may not only happen due to windows containers!

Today all Node.Js docker images are not pullable. Always check the image you are trying to pull before.

[Related Github-Issue](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/941)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem to run Windows IIS image using docker for Windows. Reading the Mohammad Trabelsi response above I realised that to solve my problem I needed to switch my containers (on docker) for Windows containers.

To do this:

1. Right click Docker instance
2. Select *"Switch to Windows containers..."*

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error in my Azure DevOps pipeline.

```
Step 1/7 : FROM nginx:alpine
alpine: Pulling from library/nginx
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries
##[error]C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe failed with return code: 1
##[section]Finishing: Build an image
```

The problem was I had selected the **Hosted VS2017** instead of the **Hosted Ubuntu**. After changing the same as follows, the build was successful.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to **update windows**  first, after that the problem has gone.

Comment: Yes!  If your version of Windows has gone out of service, you will get this error message.  Running Update will solve it!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you aren't trying to use Linux/WSL to pull a Windows image.

Use a Powershell terminal instead.

Comment: This issue could be with terminal what you are using. If you use Git bash or Linux/WSL you will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it is because of access denied to C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json
After I fixed it now it works. 
You can try to switch to Linux containers and switch back. If there is no problem with the switching, then it works with the access permission.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you must edit the file daemon.json or windows-daemon-options.json, the default location of the configuration file on Windows is %programdata%\docker\config\daemon.json  or %programdata%\docker\resources\windows-daemon-options.json

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

The optional field features on the json file, allows users to enable or disable specific daemon features. Example: {"features":{"buildkit": true}} enables buildkit as the default docker image builder.

Comment: on windows server 2019 run this: $configfile =@"
{
    "experimental":true
}
"@
$configfile|Out-File -FilePath c:\Programdata\docker\config\daemon.json -Encoding ascii -Force

restart-Service docker

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is showing this message because it is unable to find Linux containers as running. So, make sure you switch from windows to linux containers before running it.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I had the [DOCKER_HOST](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/) environment variable set. This was pointing to the WSL version of docker, even though I had stopped it in WSL the env var made Windows still use the WSL daemon.

Clearing this env var did the trick

```
Remove-Item Env:\DOCKER_HOST
```