# Docker On Windows10: No matching manifest for unknown?

Tags: docker

```
C:\Users\mites>docker pull busybox
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

How to solve this ? it occours up on every pull command.

Comment: busybox is of unix env. Try "docker pull stefanscherer/busybox-windows".  If it isn't  windows supported image then you get same response on docker pull. Try pulling windows images from docker like dotnet image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Answer (score 9):

I was running my app on Windows 10 Pro, Docker CE, windows containers when I got this error.

I switched to using linux containers and it resolved this issue for me.

Note: I was using python, reddis in this scenario for my app.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this *without* switching to Linux containers? We need Windows containers.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52102490/5587356) works without switching to Linux containers. It activates experimental features.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Windows 10 Pro.
While checking the docker logs I found more explanatory log entries:

```
[09:32:42.958][WindowsDaemon  ][Info   ] debug: a Windows version 10.0.17763-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.17134 host
[09:32:42.958][WindowsDaemon  ][Info   ] debug: no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

The solution was to update my Windows 10 Pro installation to a later version. After that, I was able to pull the image from the repo.