# Docker fails to build image on Windows for example app

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#dockerfile

Windows 10 Pro 
docker version 18.06.0-ce

after running docker build -t friendlyhello I get following error:

Sending build context to the docker daemon 5.12 KB
Step 1/7: FROM python :2.7-slim
2.7-slim : Pulling from library\python
no matching manifest for unknown in the list of entries

Comment: Maybe an intro text would be nice: I followed the tutorial of how to create a custom docker image here : LINK

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue on Windows 10. I could continue following the next steps:

- Right click Docker instance
- Go to Settings

  - Daemon
  - Advanced

    - Set the **experimental: true**

This will restart Docker and let you continue pal.