# No matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries for Node

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Am trying to configure my dockerFile and am getting an error:

**This is my docerfile:**

```
FROM node:8.14.0-stretch 
MAINTAINER Wane <Vickywane@gmail.com>

EXPOSE 8080

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install 

COPY  . /app

CMD npm start
```

**This is the error I am getting:**

> Building web
>  Step 1/9 : FROM node:8.14.0-stretch
>   8.14.0-stretch: Pulling from library/node
>  
>   ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list
>   entries

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries/55751227#55751227) there is a complete discuss to solve those problems.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the issue then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same issue on Windows 10. I could continue following the next steps:

- Right click Docker instance
- Go to Settings
- Daemon
- Advanced
- Set the experimental: true
- This will restart Docker and let you continue pal.