# docker :manifest for microsoft/windowsservercore:latest not found

Tags: windows, docker, iis, docker-for-windows

I want  to run IIS in my Docker container

[image]

But when I write this command :

```
docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore
```

I get this error :

> Using default tag: latest
>       Error response from daemon: manifest for microsoft/windowsservercore:latest not found

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548944/575643

Comment: The issue that OP is facing is due to the fact that latest tag is deprecated. 
But for others who might be facing issues like : 

`no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries` 

Refer to [stackoverflow.com/a/57548944/575643](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries/57548944#57548944) as suggested by @xpto .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Microsoft has deprecated the latest tag

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Containers/Removing-the-latest-Tag-An-Update-on-MCR/ba-p/393045

the official image with latest tag is

```
docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
```

Comment: Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:latest not found

Comment: docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

Comment: Unable to find image 'mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019' locally
ltsc2019: Pulling from windows/servercore
docker: no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: there might many possibilities for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries -- this states to turn on experiment to true. and as per this official link the images are removed because of data loss policy https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/230f7b45-0fdb-48fc-8e8f-20304e8ea0b4/failed-to-pull-windows-server-2019-container-image?forum=windowscontainers

Comment: '$ docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
Unable to find image 'mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019' locally
ltsc2019: Pulling from windows/servercore
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.'

This is the message i get while running this command.

Comment: @Aman: windows server images only run on windows, you can't run them on linux.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar and Aman, You got that error because your Docker is set to be use _Linux containers_, which is incompatible with Windows images. To switch from Linux to Windows containers you just have to right click on the Docker icon in your _system tray icons_ -- assuming you're in Windows -- and then click on "Switch to Windows containers...", as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers).

Comment: this answer is no longer vallid

Comment: Thank you yet again Microsoft.  Seriously, we love you.

Comment: Can you install this on a Mac, or do you need Windows? I'm getting `ERROR: failed to solve: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019: no match for platform in manifest sha256:..a-sha...: not found` with `docker build .` and `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 AS windows`. Also `docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries.`