# How do I build a node container with Docker on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, docker

I have the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

When I try to build I get this error

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.228MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:latest
latest: Pulling from library/node
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries
```

Node does have an image available: https://hub.docker.com/_/node

I also tried `FROM node:12-alpine`, but it gave me the same error.

Native `node` server works fine.

```
$ node server.js
Server is up on 3000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this helps: [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Most likely you are running in Windows Container Mode and must switch to Linux Container Mode. Just right click on the Docker Tray Icon in the Taskbar and open the Docker Menu. There should be an entry to do this.

(Just as a side note: I run Win 10 (latest Build) and Docker in Linux Container mode and your Dockerfile was successfully building the image here on my PC...)