# How to run Linux containers on Windows - Error while running .\docker.exe pull ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, hyper-v

I was stuck on step 6 following [this official Ubuntu tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-windows-ubuntu-hyperv-containers#0) on how to run Linux containers on Windows. I was unable to pull the Ubuntu image with

```
.\docker.exe pull ubuntu
```

I was getting error trying to run that command:

> Docker: “no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list
>   entries”

Comment: @halfer added description of specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is trying to follow [this](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-windows-ubuntu-hyperv-containers#0) official Ubuntu tutorial on how to run Linux containers on Windows than in:

Step 6. you need to use full path where you stored your `docker.exe` and `dockerd.exe` files and also you need to use `--experimental` flag after you activate experimental in Docker Desktop for Windows.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51071057/2119941) answer on how to do it.

`D:\linuxDocker\` is place where I stored `docker.exe` and `dockerd.exe`

1. `D:\linuxDocker\dockerd.exe -D --experimental --data-root C:\lcow` # Starting daemon (keep this window open, your docker daemon needs be in running state before you can proceed on step 2.)
   After that go and run :
2. `D:\linuxDocker\docker.exe pull ubuntu`

You also have to keep your Docker Desktop running while performing that.

I also had problems with Docker being slow - resolved by starting Docker with admin privileges (right click "Run as administrator") and than under Advanced gave Docker more CPU, Memory, Swap and Disk.

Follow steps before as they are in tutorial.