# How to start a nginx Docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, containers

I found some tips online but I couldn't really follow.
I tried:

```
docker run --name nginx1 -p 80:80 -d nginx
```

and got

```
Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/nginx  
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.18362 in the manifest list entries.  
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Edit: solved by running Docker in experimental mode (right click Docker Desktop instance > Settings > check Experimental features)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Comment: It does :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

That error only told you that you doesn't have the image in local storage. The next message that it will show (if you have internet access, that I suppose) it's downloading the image (and the process).