# Unable to pull hello-world image for docker in Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10

I have Docker version 19.03.5 on a Windows 10 machine. I try to run `hello-world`, but docker is not able to pull `hello-world` image:

```
docker run hello-world
```

> Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
>
> latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
>
> docker: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries.

I also tried to switch to Linux containers as suggested on some SO answers, but it throws an error:

> Unable to create - The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer 'HOST-NAME' because the object was not found. The object might have been deleted. Verify that the Virtual Machine Management service on the computer is running.

Comment: Reason and solution should be explained here: https://success.docker.com/article/error-pulling-image-no-matching-manifest .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Comment: I tried that answer which asks to switch containers type in docker desktop. But for me that itself thorows error:'Unable to create - The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer 'HOST-NAME' because the object was not found. The object might have been deleted. Verify that the Virtual Machine Management service on the computer is running.'

Answer (score 0):

There are many threads in GitHub about the second error:

> Unable to create - The running command stopped because the preference
>   variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop:
>   Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer
>   'HOST-NAME' because the object was not found. The object might have
>   been deleted. Verify that the Virtual Machine Management service on
>   the computer is running

e.g.

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3597

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1221

both of them refer to [Hyper-V Doesn't Work After Upgrade to Windows 10 1809](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee5b1d6b-09e2-49f3-a52c-820aafc316f9/hyperv-doesnt-work-after-upgrade-to-windows-10-1809?forum=win10itprovirt)

**and it suggests the following procedure:**

1. Open "**Window Security**"
2. Open "**App & Browser control**"
3. Click "**Exploit protection settings**" at the bottom
4. Switch to "**Program settings**" tab
5. Locate `C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe` in the list and expand it
6. Scroll down to "**Code flow guard (CFG)**" and uncheck "**Override system settings**"
7. Click "**Edit**"
8. Start `vmcompute` from powershell: `net start vmcompute`

Comment: I had to add vmcompute.exe to the list. Then I can see Control flow guard(not code flow guard). But "Override system settings" is already unchecked.