# Docker containers are not starting

Tags: linux, windows, docker, containers

[image]

I installed Docker (with Desktop app) on my Windows machine.
When I want to start the Desktop App I get a failure saying that I don't have enough memory to start it.
When I switch the containers to Windows Containers the desktop app works but I can't pull any image from the docker hub (for example docker pull/run hello-world).

I'am getting this Error :

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\docker-cli\tools\docker.exe: no matching 
manifest for 
windows/amd64 10.0.16299 in the manifest list entries.
See 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\docker-cli\tools\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Is there any solution ?

Thanks a lot .

Comment: So what's actually your question? How to overcome memory issue with linux containers or why images are not fetched?

Comment: Please post formatted code rather than screenshots. Screenshots break search, copy and paste, and are less accessible.

Comment: @leopal Both ! i need a solution to start the containers .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)