# My docker can't come up anymore with elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

My docker container used to start successfully. As of this weekend it fails pulling elasticsearch. Please help (Windows 10 64bit)

```
> docker-compose up
Pulling elastic (elasticsearch:7.3.1)...
7.3.1: Pulling from library/elasticsearch
ERROR: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17763 in the manifest list entries

> docker manifest inspect -v library/elasticsearch:latest
no such manifest: docker.io/library/elasticsearch:latest
```

Part of the docker-compose.yml

```
  elastic:
    image: elasticsearch:7.3.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - Elogger.level=TRACE
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata:/data/elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9201:9200"
    networks:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this post [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

1. Right click Docker icon in the Windows System Tray
2. Go to Settings
3. Daemon
4. Advanced
5. Set the "experimental": true
6. Restart Docker

Comment: I went to Settings, but I can't find Daemon :(

Comment: Thanks for the link, another solution within the link helped me. `On Windows, you can locate the config file directly at '%programdata%\docker\config\daemon.json' and set the attributes there. `

Comment: I have this error on Mac

Answer (score -1):

no idea why you have `library/elasticsearch:7.3.1` in your compose file.. according to official elasticsearch images the path is simply `elasticsearch:7.3.1 - feel free to edit thet compose file and remove`library/` part from image name

Comment: The compose file is not from me. Anyway, I checked it and it just containes `elasticsearch:7.3.1`.

Comment: could you kindly share the content of compose file here?

Comment: have you done `docker login` before using `docker-compose up`? Maybe it is trying to pull from other registry than the dockerhub.

Comment: Yes, I am logged it. I added the config part

Comment: I see the issue now. Problem is that image is built for Linux architecture. Please try to switch to linux containers:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M94iU.png