# Docker Installation Error on Step 1/11 ./bin/acore-docker-build

Tags: docker, azerothcore

Having failed to install azerothcore normally, I have now tried to install it using docker.

But I am already running into an issue, probably because I am not very experienced with docker.

When I input `./bin/acore-docker-build`, it fails at step one, outputting this message:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  862.4MB
Step 1/11 : FROM ubuntu:bionic
bionic: Pulling from library/ubuntu
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.18362 in the manifest list entries
Unable to find image 'acbuild:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for acbuild, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

I am not sure what I am supposed to do about this. I am logged into a basic docker account. I went to the docker.exe referenced in the above message and changed permissions for the account running docker to have full permissions. No change. I ran git as administrator. No change.

What should I be doing differently?

Thanks for reading. Willing to clarify anything.

Also, I am using windows 10.

Comment: So what fails for you is `docker build <something>`? Can you run some random command just to check if your docker deamon is set up correctly? `docker run ubuntu:bionic whoami`

Comment: I'm not sure if this indicates success or failure, but this is what it output:
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:bionic' locally

bionic: Pulling from library/ubuntu

docker: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.18362 in the manifest list entries.

See 'docker run --help'.


Also, I am not sure whether this is a general failure of "docker build x", since I have not tried to build anything else and do not know what I would build anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to have Docker for Desktop opened up and Docker daemon running (icon from bottom left should be green).