# Unable to pull docker image on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, hyper-v

I have docker 2.2.0.4 on Windows 10. I see following message while trying to test it:

> >docker pull hello-world
>
> Using default tag: latest
>
> latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
>
> no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries

I even did 'Switch to Linux Containers', but that stops docker itself with error.

How to get it working?

I tried with 2.2.0.5 too, but still I face issues. I have posted it [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/error-while-starting-docker/92183) too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Answer (score 2):

Try running with the Linux platform as an option

```
docker pull --platform linux
```

> OR

Enable the experimental feature in Docker Daemon

1. Right click Docker icon in the Windows System Tray
2. Go to Settings
3. Daemon
4. Advanced
5. Set the "experimental": true
6. Restart Docker

Comment: Your answer is copied exactly from the URL that I had provided above.

Comment: If you see, I have added two different options and as I am using Windows as well.

Comment: I don't see Daemon in settings.