# Docker "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries" in Node js

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to dockerize a simple node js hello world app but having this issue. I 'll paste the error below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XwxO.png)

Comment: Please avoid posting code as images. Rather, copy the code and the error messages as text and format it as a code block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Comment: I tried it. when I'm switching to containers I'm getting that 'memory is not enough' error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to right-click on the docker icon and switch to linux containers

Comment: I did it. it says not enough memory..my pc ram is 4gb and running on 2 cores. is this the reason why im unable to run it?

Comment: I’d imagine so.. If you look in the docket preferences you should be able to bump the memory usage, but obviously don’t let docker use all of your 4GB.