# Run windows container on docker toolbox?

Tags: docker, windows-container

I am trying to run microsoft/iis:latest image on my docker toolbox set-up in my Windows 10 Home.
As expected, with the containers running on a virtual linux VM, i get the below message.

```
$ docker run -it microsoft/iis
Unable to find image 'microsoft/iis:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from microsoft/iis
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Is there a way i can run such containers on toolbox, without using 'Docker for Windows' set-up?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you cannot run Windows containers in Windows Home. Windows containers run directly in the OS without the intervention of Docker Desktop. Docker Desktop is only a convenient interface in this case.

You can install in Virtualbox Microsoft Hyper-V Server with is free and there (I think) you can run Windows Containers.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. so there is way around to get full set up on windows 10 Home.