# Docker for Desktop error during connect: Post A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I have freshly installed Docker for Desktop Edge in Windows 10 Home and try to build an image using the docker build command. But unfortunately, it didn't work for me, and got the below error :

CMD -   `docker build -t heet1996/post:0.0.1 .`

```
error during connect: Post https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=na8ugnpn6d8gnxl3z8ppx4gap&shmsize=0&t=heet1996%2Fpost%3A0.0.1&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

[image]

Earlier I was using a docker toolbox so I had to remove all the environment variables related to the Docker in my User variables before installing Docker for Desktop. **After a lot of search on GitHub issues, I am still not getting the solution.**

This is what I found in my service.txt file (C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\service.txt)

`[18:27:22.232][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [f9b6b957] <Server end> POST http://localhost/dns/refresh-hosts -> 204 NoContent (took 118ms)`

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when i un-installed the docker toolbox and installed the docker desktop.

**System Configuration:**
OS: Windows 10 Home
Version: 21H1

**Steps I Followed:**

1. Un-installed the docker desktop.
2. Removed the all dockers related environment variables from the user variables.
   **Navigation:** This System-> Properties-> Advance System Settings-> Environment Variables-> User Variables.
3. Re-installed the docker desktop and it's started working properly.

Comment: For me this even worked without reinstalling docker desktop. I only removed the Docker enviroment variables and restarted the Terminal app.

Answer (score 1):

**here we are talking about using Docker with PowerShell and not with WSL. And also following the addition of variables in the environment variables of Windows.**

**Configuration when this response was made:**

- **Windows 10 Pro 20H2 (Build 19042.867)**
- **Docker 20.10.5**
- **Powershell 5.1.19041.610**

I also had to configure docker in a dirty way too much, after several hours of research and a comparison of installation on a clean Windows 10 I understood where my error was.

In addition to the user environment variable also make sure that you do not have DOCKER variables in the Windows system environment variables either.

**Here is where my error was, I think it was due to the installation of the Docker module**

[image]

I had the **DOCKER_HOST** variable in my system variable environment, so i deleted it.

If you want to check all your environment variables with Powershell:

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables()
```

If you really want a Docker fresh installation on Windows, you need to delete the following folders:

```
C:\ProgramData\Docker
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker
$HOME\AppData\Local\Docker
$HOME\AppData\Roaming\Docker
$HOME\AppData\Roaming\Docker Desktop
$HOME\.docker
```

my error, therefore, produced this error:

**ERROR ==>** `error during connect: Get http://docker.artofshell:2376/v1.24/version: dial tcp: lookup docker.artofshell: no such host`

[image]

After a complete uninstall of all docker *(Via chocolatey, official docker ...)* and by properly installing Docker from the official executable [here](https://www.docker.com/get-started) everything is back to normal

Then if you want to use docker via Powershell you have to change the configuration of DockerCLI as you can see on many answers

[image]

---

### Conclusion

- It is possible to use docker with Powershell you must check if the
  server daemon is used by `Windows/amd64`, you can modify the daemon with this command `cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"; .\DockerCli.exe  -SwitchDeamon`
- You can check the configuration of the daemon with the following command: `docker version`
- You must remove all traces of old Docker installations if you had any
- You must delete the environment variables from the old installation or from the docker toolbox
- You must also activate the experimental features: information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66606000/12317483)

Comment: This solution works without reinstalling, I also had no env variables that I could remove

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it on Docker CLI instead of CMD

Answer (score 0):

#### Docker for windows must have:

- [✓] Updated Windows 10 version >=2004
- [✓] WSL 2 and Default Distro (i.e ubuntu)

The steps are well documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#simplified-installation-for-windows-insiders). These are what to do after the installation:

1. To confirm ubuntu's installation, open `C:/Windows/System32/bash.exe` aka `bash`.
2. To test if docker is properly installed, run `docker version` on `bash`. This should print the docker client and server engine.
3. After successfully tested and confirmed the installations, try entering your command

```
$ docker build -t heet1996/post:0.0.1 .
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Powershell as Administrator and run the below commands

`cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"`

`./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon`