# Docker Launching Microsoft nanoserver container on Windows

Tags: docker

I am starting with Docker and trying to launch a very simple command to pull the "nanoserver" container:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:2004
```

The output of this command is

> 2004: Pulling from windows/nanoserver
>
> no matching manifest for **linux/amd64** in the manifest list entries

Why is Docker complaining about not finding "linux" in the manifest of the image if I am trying to execute in pure Windows?

Also, how can I see the contents of that "manifest" ?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries

Comment: Especially the second answer.