# Azure DevOps hosted-agent failed to pull windows:2004

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

When using `Windows-2019` [hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) (Agent installed with 1809 windows version -[Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md)) as Agent Specification, We can't pull `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:2004` docker image.

Exception:

[image]

I'm familiar with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries) (Which works perfectly locally).
But, since Docker Desktop doesn't install on the agent I can't switch to Windows containers. Moreover, Install Docker Desktop is not an option since reboot required.

Currently, Creating a build machine is not an option.

So my question is: There is a way to pull `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:2004` docker image from the hosted agent?

Comment: Have you checked this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-2004%2Cwindows-10-2004)?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Yes, but how does it help me? am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is: There is a way to pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows:2004 docker image from the hosted agent?

I am afraid there is no such way to pull `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:2004` docker image from the hosted agent.

That because [Matching container host version with container image versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-2019%2Cwindows-10-1809#windows-server-containers):

> Windows Server containers and the underlying host share a single
> kernel, the container’s base image must match that of the host. If the
> versions are different, the container may start, but full functionally
> isn't guaranteed.

In other words, Windows requires the host OS version to match the container OS version. If you want to run a container based on a newer Windows build, make sure you have an equivalent host build. Otherwise, you can use Hyper-V isolation to run older containers on new host builds.

**So**, we could not pull the image `windows:2004` (`2004`) from the hosted agent `windows-latest` OR `windows-2019` (`1809`). We could only pull the image `windows:1809` with the hosted agent.

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809
```

[image]

**However**, if I pull the image `windows:1903` with hosted agent, I will get the error `no matching manifest for windows/amd64...`. In order to verify my answer, I use the private agent, which hosted on the windows version `1903` (OS build `18362`), It works fine.

In summary, we cannot pull windows:2004 (2004) image on the hosted agent (1809). The workaround for this request is that use the private agent.

BTW, I have tested those solutions which mentioned in [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries) in your question with private agent. Neither `switch to Linux containers` nor `set the "experimental": true` can solve this error.

The Reference links:

[List of Microsoft Windows versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions)

[Unable to pull images from microsoft](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3761)

Comment: Any estimation time when these images will be available? It's kinda weird that the current hosted agent based on a version which 2 years + old