# Docker and mysql problems?

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I like to set up a LAMP on a docker.
I work on an i386 architecture.
I have some issues regarding the sql part.

I tried to do my own docker-compose.yml, and tried serveral other source but i encounter always the following problems :
When I do

> docker-compose up -d

I always have an ERROR on the sql part :

- MARIADB
  Building database Step 1/1 : FROM mariadb:10.3
  10.3: Pulling from library/mariadb ERROR: Service 'database' failed to
  **build: no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries**
- MYSQL
  8.0: Pulling from library/mysql
  **ERROR: no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries**

I understand that there is no mariadb/sql on manifst...

Can you please tell me what goes wrong, or/and how can i setup a php-mysql-phpmyadmin on docker with an i386 under Debian?

EXEMPLE :
The last source code i've tried is
https://github.com/jcavat/docker-lamp

I also tried to use

```
Example stack.yml for mariadb:

# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

then

```
docker-compose -f stack.yml up
```

It result by the same error

```
Pulling db (mariadb:)...
latest: Pulling from library/mariadb
ERROR: no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Comment: Docker isn't documented to work on (32-bit) i386 Linux, only (64-bit) x86\_64.