# Image adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9 not available

Tags: java, jenkins, dockerhub, adoptopenjdk, openj9

Some days ago our jenkins builds broken because the image "**adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9**" was not available on docker hub. This is the error:

```
docker pull adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9
no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

It seems that image war renamed to "**adoptopenjdk:11-jdk-openj9**". Is it right? Is there any documentation of this change?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9

Comment: I see the image on docker hub (using browser), but when I try to pull I get the error

Comment: What is you operating system?

Comment: The error happens on windows (with WSL enbaled) and on linux with same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Comment: I'm already on Linux container and the message says "no matching manifest for linux/amd64 ...". So I think this is a different problem.

Comment: Why don't you simply pull a tagged image instead of the `latest` one?

Comment: I can switch to another tag but I have to change all pipelines. This means that "latest" tag of "adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9" is broken but I cannot find other with same problem. So I would like understand if problem is in my systems or in docker image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some checks on my system and other images I discovered that the "latest" tag of image "adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9" is broken.

To fix the problem you can use a different tag (I switched to "adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:alpine" and it works).
There's a similar bug for "adoptopenjdk/openjdk12-openj9" here
https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/issues/194.

I've also open a bug for this problem here: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/issues/610